# How do I make a game engine in a game? (with HTML5 and Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, controls

I want to make an operating system for the character in my HTML5/Javascript game, and I don't want to use libraries.

I found something about controlling my character with my mouse and arrows, and it worked for me, but I want to go deeper into this subject.

---

SO: the thing is:
I want to control my character smoothly, en when I jump, it automatically turn down, etc.

[Here is an example](http://clay.io/) of what I mean. When you go to this webpage, there is a little guy all the way left of the screen. You can walk with the W/A/S/D keys with this character through the website. How do I make such a little guy?

I hope this was enough (maybe a lot) information to describe my problem. Maybe there are some nice tutorials about this subject.

Comment: Do you mean 'Game Engine' when you say 'Operating System'? As, there is a considerable difference, and both are probably too broad a topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: What does this have to do with an operating system?

Comment: Sorry the title of this topic is really bad, I am sorry for that. What I mean is how to make a game engine with only HTML5 and javascript

Comment: Now that u threw me the word game engine u helped me a lot. I was looking for that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: These examples from the Phaser game engine might help: http://examples.phaser.io

Comment: Wow, this will definitely help me! Thanks a lot!